# Use Gradle custom plugin in buildscript thats part of the project itself

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a gradle buildscript and I want to use a plugin custom in it that  that's inside of source code of this project. But I'm not sure how to do it.

```
apply plugin: 'my-custom-plugin'
```

and in this same project as this buildfile I have a plugin file thats inside `src/main/groovy/MyCustomPlugin.groovy`. I also have `my-custom-plugin.properties` file set up under `resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/my-custom-plugin.properties`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only officially supported way to achieve this is to put the plugin into `$rootDir/buildSrc/src/main/groovy`. (Classes in `buildSrc` are automatically added to the build script class path of the main build.) But if you plan to use the same plugin from other builds, and therefore want to publish the plugin as part of the build, you'll need to have a separate build for the plugin.

Comment: I want to use this plugin in other projects also. Was thinking that it would be nice that I could use it on plugins project also